# How can I change image file names with Paperclip when already in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using Rails with Paperclip and S3 for image uploads, and I've had it running in production for a while. Now I'm trying to update the way images are saved (to create more readable filenames), but I'm not sure how to change the path without breaking all the images that have already been uploaded.

Any thoughts on a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Lets say your model is Avatar.

1. Create a copy of your model, say OldAvatar. Set table name in this model to 'avatars'
2. In Avatar model, set the paperclip path/filename as you want it to be.
3. Now you can write a rake task which will loop through each OldAvatars and create new Avatars using the OldAvatar image file

Note: You have to delete the OldAvatars in the loop, and probably save necessary fields like user_id, etc..

Comment: I like this... gonna give it a try. I'll keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it but try

rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=class_name

I have used it to refresh the style size of the attachment. I don't know whether it works or not. Just give it a try.